# Trying to check for everyone that reacted discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So supposedly this is suppose to check to see who reacted to the message I have sent to everyone! But it has an error `list index out of range`

Here is the code

```
@client.command()
async def public(ctx, winners: int, time: int, link:str, *, prize:str):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == '୨୧┊giveaway'):
                embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f"**Giving Away {prize}**",
                description = f"React with  to enter! \n **{winners}** winner \n \n  Must be in **[this server]({link})** to enter!", color=0xf9c900)
                msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await msg.add_reaction('')
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == '୨୧┊giveaway'):
                    reactors = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
                    winnersgoal = random.choice(reactors)
                    winnermessage = await channel.send(f"Hey {winnersgoal}! You have won {prize}! Please come and collect them [here](https://discord.gg/)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the message again with its ID to get the updated state of the message.

```py
@client.command()
async def public(ctx, winners: int, time: int, link:str, *, prize:str):
    channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name='୨୧┊giveaway')
    if channel:
        embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"**Giving Away {prize}**",
        description = f"React with  to enter! \n **{winners}** winner \n \n  Must be in **[this server]({link})** to enter!", color=0xf9c900)
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        reactors = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        winnersgoal = random.choice(reactors)
        winnermessage = await channel.send(f"Hey {winnersgoal}! You have won {prize}! Please come and collect them [here](https://discord.gg/)")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Channel Not Found")
```

Comment: This does not work! I got this error `reactors = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()`

Comment: you need to react with some emoji